# Eclipse suddenly giving parser exception errors on previously working code - Android, Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I haven't worked on this project in about a week. I've changed nothing at all in the code, but today I open it up and try to launch the Android activity, and Eclipse tells me there are errors:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdklib.xml.AndroidManifestParser.parse(AndroidManifestParser.java:608)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper.parse(AndroidManifestHelper.java:71)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerDeltaVisitor.visit(PreCompilerDeltaVisitor.java:209)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:68)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:48)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.build(PreCompilerBuilder.java:255)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
```

There are indeed ">" or "/>" after each "activity" in my Manifest file.  The only thing that I can think that would cause this, is I moved the folder containing Eclipse.exe from off my desktop, where I had originally downloaded it to, into a sub-folder elsewhere.  I've moved it back to my Desktop, but the same error persists.  And I am not sure why that would have anything to do with it, but there have been zero changes since the last time I opened this, and it was working just fine then.

Oh, one other thing, I ran Ccleaner the other day, but I don't know how that could be causing this.  But I'm at a loss to figure out where this error is coming from.  Any ideas?

Comment: May or may not help -- but after trying all these things, I eventually decided to just close Eclipse, and re-open it.  And the issues went away! -- I'm using version 4.2.0 of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...an external jar was not being found.  I thought those would be added into the workspace, and not called from their origin, e.g. from \Downloads.  Apparently not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this at all?  What .jar, and what did you do to resolve the issue?  I'm facing literally the same issue, and the XML looks fine to me.  I've never moved Eclipse though, and if it was referencing something from my downloads folder, it should still be there...

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Right click on the project and refresh.
Then do a "Project -> Clean", make sure that "Build Automatically" (under Project) is checked.

This might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check a few things

1. Is the AVD Manager still available to eclipse. Go to Preferences --> Android and if see if you can see all the AVDs
2. Clean the project. If the project has libraries attached to it (eg. LVL), clean all the projects. (Project --> Clean) and then build them again. (First build the library then the project)
3. If the issue still persists, delete the folder 'gen' from projects. Dont worry, this will be regenerated.
4. If you are using library, make sure the library is available for project. Check this in Project Property.

If you are connected to SVN, make sure SVN is not locked when you do these operations.